# Problem about tangent vector and the inclusion map of the unit circle.

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, analysis, manifolds

[image]

It is so complecated for me. Please can you show how to solve. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We have
$$i_*\left(\frac{\partial}{\partial \bar{x}}\right)(x) = \frac{\partial}{\partial \bar{x}}(i^*x)$$
and likewise
$$i_*\left(\frac{\partial}{\partial \bar{x}}\right)(y) = \frac{\partial}{\partial \bar{x}}(i^*y).$$

Given that the text defines $\bar{x}=i^*x$ and $\bar{y}=i^*y$, can you solve it from here?

The complete solution for $x$:
$$i_*\left(\frac{\partial}{\partial\bar{x}}\right)(x) = \frac{\partial}{\partial\bar{x}}(i^*x) = \frac{\partial}{\partial\bar{x}}(\bar{x})=1$$

Comment: Please can you solve this only for $x$ from here. I Will be able to do the solution for $y$ by myself if you Will show. By the way, for part-b, how do I follow a way to prove?

Comment: Thank you for completeding of the question :)

Comment: By the way, is that all? It is so esay but i look difficult. Well, for the part-b, how do I express these in general?

Comment: That's all. It's really not that hard. I don't really see the point of part b) to be honest, since exactly the same calculation applies. These things are local after all.

Comment: Okay that is not difficult really. Thank you for help:)